# leaflet js popup IE not looking ok

Tags: internet-explorer, maps, leaflet

I'm using leaflet js for maps and its default popups.
I included the proper css rule for IE (), but popups do not look properly on the map (see screenshot below).

I'm using IE9 at the moment for tests, so the css rule for IE<9 do not apply anyway.

When I go to leaflet js official site examples, popups look ok.

What am I missing?

Thanks

[image: screeshot]

Comment: on all other browsers everything is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using twitter bootstrap in this project, and that's the cause of the popup thing on IE

edit: my bad bad bad, I was including ie special css for everything, not conditionally... screw me !